# Mysql5.6 and problem of php5-mysql , mysql-common packages

Tags: apt, mysql, php

I install Mysql 5.6 with this [documentaion](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mysql-5.6-on-ubuntu-12.10-including-memcached-plugin)(in ubuntu 13.04) , now I need to install php5-mysql and mysql-common packages. can I install them with apt-get? I think they will install mysql5.5 compatible, may some error occure! how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need mysql-common? Mysql client is already there. I am not sure about Ubuntu 12.10, but on 12.04 its in `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin`.

`/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin/mysql` will give you mysql shell. If you do not want to use full path, add `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin/` to your ENV.

I added it in `/etc/environment` so my `$PATH` looks like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin"
```

Then just run `source /etc/environment` command and hit `which mysql`. You should see `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin/mysql` in output.

For php5-mysql, you can instead install `php5-mysqlnd`.

Comment: how can I use `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin`?

Comment: Please checked edited answer. I added more details above. I hope it will help.